# How to input the unknown size of time-step to TimeDistributed Keras layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have my input state with shape = (84,84,4)

```
state = Input(shape=(84,84,4), dtype="float")
```

So I want to pass this to some TimeDistributed layer with time steps size=1..5 (in range of 1 to 5) and I don't know exactly which it equals.

My next layer is something like this:

```
conv1 = TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(16, 8, 8, subsample=(4, 4), border_mode='valid',
                                      activation='relu', dim_ordering='tf'))(state)
```

And I've got an error at this layer:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I just want to **pass** an unknown time-series size to TimeDistributed and then to LSTM also.

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

So basically in Keras - you need to provide the sequence length because during computations Keras layers accepts as an input `numpy` array with a specified shape - what makes compulsory for all inputs (at least in one batch) to have a length fixed. But - you still can deal with varying input size by 0-padding (making all sequence equal size by adding all zero dummy timesteps at the beginning) and then [masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) what makes your network equivalent to a varying length input network.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a variable sequence-length, like this :

```
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(64,(3,3)),input_shape=(None,None,None,3)))
```

But now you will have to adjust the length of the vector when it flattens or un-rolls at the time prediction.